# Найти сумму максимальных элементов третьей строки и шестого столбца матрицы соответственно

Tags: python

в этом коде последним пунктом должно идти указанное в теме условие, вообще нет идей как делать, подскажите, пожалуйста

```
n=int(input("n="))

m=int(input("m="))

a=[]

a=[[0]*m for i in range(n)]

import random

for i in range(n):

for j in range(m):
    a[i][j]=random.randint(-10,10)
    print( "{:4d}".format(a[i][j]), end = "")
print()

count=0
for row in a:
    for x in row:
        if x>0 and x%3==0:
        count+=1
print("Количество положительных элементов, кратных числу 3, в каждой строке матрицы = ", count)

sum=0 
max=10
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
```

Comment: в заголовке нет никакого условия. Ищешь два максимума и складываешь два числа. Просто как два пальца

Comment: найти сумму максимальных элементов третьей строки и шестого столбца матрицы соответственно

Comment: надо же как-то указать на строку и столбец

Comment: Обходи в цикле фор по индексу

Answer (score 0):

Do not use built-in function names 'max' and 'sum'.

```
n=int(input("n="))

m=int(input("m="))

a=[]

a=[[0]*m for i in range(n)]

import random

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        a[i][j]=random.randint(-10,10)
        print( "{:4d}".format(a[i][j]), end = "")
    print()

count=0
for row in a:
    for x in row:
        if x>0 and x%3==0:
            count+=1
print("Количество положительных элементов, кратных числу 3, в каждой строке матрицы = ", count)
print(a[2])


# Task: max row 3 + max column 6
max_row3 = max(a[3 - 1])
list_column6 = []
for i in range(n):
    # This's loop of column
    list_column6.append(int(a[i][6 - 1]))
max_column6 = max(list_column6)
print('max row 3 + max column 6 =', max_row3 + max_column6)
```

out:

```
n=4
m=7
  -4  -2   2  -6   7  -5   2
   7  -1   3   3   6  -7  -1
  -6  -8  -3   1  10   2  10
  -1 -10   7   0  -6  -1  -2
Количество положительных элементов, кратных числу 3, в каждой строке матрицы =  3
[-6, -8, -3, 1, 10, 2, 10]
max row 3 + max column 6 = 12
```

Answer (score 0):

из ваших формулировок не вполне понятно чего вы хотите.

вот так можно найти сумму максимальных значений 3 строки и 6 колонки (по индексу):

```
max_3 = max(a[3])
max_6 = max([c[6] for c in a])
sum_3_6 = max_3 + max_6
```

если надо найти сумму элементов 3 строки, значение которых равно максимуму в этой строке, и сумму элементов 6 колонки значение которых равно максимальному значению в этой колонке:

```
sum_3 = sum(i for i in a[3] if i==max_3)
sum_6 = sum(c[6] for c in a if c[6]==max_6)
```

например:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randint(-10, 10, size=(7, 7))
'''
для 
array([[ -1,   4,   5,   6,   0,  -8,  -2],
       [  2,  -6,   7,  -3,   5,  -6,  -5],
       [  3,   4,   5,  -8,  -9,  -3,  -2],
       [ -4,  -7,   0,  -9,  -1,   3,  -8],
       [  0,  -4,   1,   6,   1,   6,   1],
       [ -6,  -9,   6,   2,  -5,   8,  -5],
       [  7,  -3,  -9,  -2,  -1, -10,   1]])

результат:

max_3 = 3
max_6 = 1
sum_3_6 = 4
sum_3 = 3
sum_6 = 2
'''
```